# Implement Slack authorisation via OAuth 2.0 in Apple Watch App

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, apple-watch, slack-api

I need to integrate the Slack API in the Apple Watch Application. I need to authorize the user by his slack email and password. But looking into the Slack API docs, I understood we can implement OAuth 2.0 authorization. How can I implement that slack authorization in the Apple Watch application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the user authenticate with Slack via iOS mobile application and store the OAuth tokens (Including the refresh token) in a shared resource group so the Apple Watch application can access the information. If the user tries to use the Apple Watch app when the tokens are not stored yet; Alert the user to open the mobile application and login with Slack if they have not done so already.

I recommend putting any Slack API call functions in a shared local framework so both the mobile application and any other extensions (In case you want to expand to notification center widget etc) can use them in the future.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Is there any other way that we can do it without using the iOS mobile application? As I don't want to do any iOS mobile app and its a standalone watch app.

Comment: Briefly from me looking at how they handle user login I would say no. You will need to implement a mobile application to present a safari based authentication via the OAuth flow.

Comment: Sean, we had finally implementing the OAuth on webpage and then doing the validation as designed. Thanks